# array of dynamic imagebuttons first control's event not firing

Tags: vb.net, dynamic-controls

I am trying to display ImageButtons dynamically, which I have been able to do. I also want an event to fire when I click on those dynamic ImageButtons. I have the dynamic controls loaded in an ArrayList. I am able to have an event fire for all of the dynamic ImageButtons in the ArrayList except the **first** ImageButton in the ArrayList.

I am very new to VB.Net so any help or suggestions will be appreciated. Here is my code below (I tried to include only the relevant code):

```
    Dim aryImg As New ArrayList

    For k = 0 To 10 

        sqlImgs.readData()
        Dim img As New ImageButton
        img.CommandName = "imgClick"
        img.CommandArgument = k
        AddHandler img.Click, AddressOf onClick

        aryImg.Add(img)
        aryImg(k).imageurl = sqlImgs.getData("picLoc")
        aryImg(k).id = sqlImgs.getData("lTitle")

        aryImg(k).width = "160"
        aryImg(k).height = "240"
    Next

    Private Sub onClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Label1.Text = sender.id.ToString

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a work around for my problem. I was calling the data using a DataReader and when I changed it to a DataSet the issue went away. Although, I am still not sure why the DataReader would prevent only one of many dynamic imagebuttons from firing events.